# c# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn selectedValue spread throughout the whole line

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I'm stuck with the following problem:

i build a dataGridView with 7 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn, adding with the following code

```cs
foreach (string jour in Enum.GetNames(typeof(Jours)))
        {
            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboboxColumn = CreateComboBoxColumn();
            List<Journee> myJourneeList = new List<Journee>(mydatas.journeeTypeList.ToList());
            comboboxColumn.DataSource = myJourneeList;
            comboboxColumn.DisplayMember = "name";
            comboboxColumn.ValueMember = "id";
            comboboxColumn.DataPropertyName = "id";
            comboboxColumn.HeaderText = jour;
            dataGridView_machineSemaines.Columns.Add(comboboxColumn);
            setSelectedValue(jour, myJourneeList);
        }
```

I get the following dataGridView :

[image]

then if i selected a new value in one combobox :

[image]

and if a i scroll (with the horizontal-scroll) (or if i open an other tab and come back to this tab), then the whole row get the same selectedValue :

[image]

how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `DataPropertyName` for all columns. So the behavior is expected. In fact, all columns are showing a single value. The `id` property of your data source of grid.

If you want them to show different values, use different `DataPropertyName` or in another word, bind them to different columns.